# UIScrollView override

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

There's a private method of the UIScrollView that should allow me to control the speed of a content offset animation. But when I override it in my class like so ...

```
- (void)setContentOffsetAnimationDuration:(CFTimeInterval)value
{
    _contentOffsetAnimationDuration = 10;
}

[self setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```

I get a compiler error like this ...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIScrollView._contentOffsetAnimationDuration", referenced from:
      -[HistoryScrollView setContentOffsetAnimationDuration:] in HistoryScrollView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas. I really don't want to roll some clunky animation code into this. It's so tantalisingly close to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean '_setContentOffsetAnimationDuration'. Do something like this:

```
[myScrollView _setContentOffsetAnimationDuration:10];
```

Although, it will get you rejected from the App Store. The reviewers run static analysers now that detect any usage of private APIs.